# How to pass id to a modal within same page using GET method?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, get, modal-dialog

I have a following link:

```
<a type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal"
                                    data-target="#product_view" href="?id='.$row['upcoming_event_id'].'">
                                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i> Read more</a>
```

The read more looks like this: 
[image]

When I press the read more button, a modal will pop up like this:

[image]

I tried the following code but it's not working:

```
<div class="modal fade product_view" id="product_view">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="class pull-right"><span
                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
                <h3 class="modal-title">I want to show the event id here <?php echo $_GET['id']; ?></h3>
            </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

How to solve this? Or is there any better way to do this? I have to show the id into the modal, not on another page. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want to solve?

Comment: When I press the read more button, I have to fetch the related data from database and show that into the modal. Thats why I am targeting with upcoming_event_id. #Nagaraju

Comment: I probably wouldn't use the `href` attribute to pass the ID. I feel that implies the button will take the user to a new page. I'd suggest using a data attribute e.g. `data-event-id="<?php echo $event_id; ?>"` then accessing the ID within the javascript that opens the modal. However I can't fully answer the question as I don't know if you are able to change the code that opens the modal. I presume this is javascript that controls that.

Comment: I guess you are using bootstrap, if so refer this https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#varying-modal-content

Comment: As the modal is in the same page and I have to send the data to that modal, I used href="?id=something" . #C2486

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP code execute first, so you can't set PHP value for `$_GET` dynamically. Use a javascript function.

```
function setEventId(event_id){
    document.querySelector("#event_id").innerHTML = event_id;
}
```

Call `setEventId()` function from anchor tag

```
<a type="button" onclick="setEventId(<?= $row['upcoming_event_id'] ?>)" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal"
                                    data-target="#product_view" href="javascript:void(0)">
                                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i> Read more</a>
```

And use `<span id="event_id"></span>` to replace html value with `event_id`

```
<div class="modal fade product_view" id="product_view">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="class pull-right"><span
                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
                <h3 class="modal-title">I want to show the event id here <span id="event_id"></span></h3>
            </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is demo example after getting  value of `$row['upcoming_event_id']` or page load.

```js
function setEventId(event_id){
    document.querySelector("#event_id").innerHTML = event_id;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<a type="button" onclick="setEventId(1)" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal"
                                    data-target="#product_view" href="javascript:void(0)">
                                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i> Read more</a>
                                    
<a type="button" onclick="setEventId(2)" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal"
                                    data-target="#product_view" href="javascript:void(0)">
                                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i> Read more</a>
                                    
                                    
<a type="button" onclick="setEventId(3)" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal"
                                    data-target="#product_view" href="javascript:void(0)">
                                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i> Read more</a>
                                    
<div class="modal fade product_view" id="product_view">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="class pull-right"><span
                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
                <h3 class="modal-title">I want to show the event id here <span id="event_id"></span></h3>
            </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: #C2486 Thanks for your solution. It is working fine. But I want to send multiple values using setEventID() function. I have tried this : onclick="setEventId('.$row['upcoming_event_id'].',' .$row['upcoming_event_description'].')"                                            But It is not working. Can you tell me how to pass multiple values here?

Answer (score 1):

On your button add a data attribute containing your id, like this :

```
<a type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal"
                                    data-target="#product_view" data-id="'.$row['upcoming_event_id'].'" href="?id='.$row['upcoming_event_id'].'">
                                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i> Read more</a>
```

Then in JS you need no write an event listener function automatically called when your modal is open. for your need this function seems like :

```
$('#product_view').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) 
  var id = button.data('id') 

  var modal = $(this)
  modal.find('.modal-title').text('I want to show the event id here ' + id)
})
```

See official documentation [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#varying-modal-content)

Comment: #Gildas Ross I have to fetch all data related to that id from database. But from your code, I get the id using javascript, not php. Then how can I getch all data from database?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to use html data attribute on your  tag. let's say :

```
<a href="#openModal_edit" data-idValue="<?= $row['upcoming_event_id'] ?>" ...</a>
```

Then you need to create onclick event handler, maybe on your modal button to extract your data attribute :

```
onclick="myId=this.dataset.idValue;document.querySelector('#THE_HTMLID_THAT_YOUWANT_DISPLAY_IDVALUE').value = myId;return true;"
```

and make sure in querySelector you add the element id that you want show the value on it.